# Design Counter With Arbitrary Sequence Using Load

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, counter

I'm trying to design an asynchronous counter with JK flip- flops, with an arbitrary sequence.

[image]

The sequence is: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2 ?

I know how to solve this kind of problems, but in this case how can one solve this problem with the 6 and 7 ? Because a state can only have one next state ?

Edit: This is what I did so far after doing the K maps. I get J2 = 0, K2 = Q1, J1 = 0, K1 = 0, J0 = 0, K0 = Q2Q1. But when I try to simulate it in multisim, it gets stuck to 0. Did I make a mistake in my k map simplifications or is there an issue my circuit ?

N.B.  in this image, Q1 is the LSB, Q2 is the '2' bit, Q3 is '4'

[image]

Comment: is this a school assignment? .... how does it get to state 6 or state 7 ?

Comment: yes, i have no idea how it can get to the state 6 or 7...

Comment: Then you also have no idea how it can get to 0.

Comment: Use a PROM to control the state machine.

Comment: Design such that the next state of 6 and 7 is state-2.

Comment: Voting to close as the problem behind this question simple isn't answerable until you have a **complete specification**.  With what you have right now there are many approaches that could be taken, but each would rely on **unvalidated assumptions** as to what behavior is actually desired.  **Don't guess or ask us to** - re-read the requirement, have a discussion with the stakeholders, or examine the application to more carefully determine the need.

Comment: This is not "an asynchronous counter" - it is a synchronous counter, as evidenced by a common clock.

Answer (score 1):

You have two conditions to consider:

- Current state not > 4: next state is increment
- Current state > 4: next state is go to 2

That works out to one logic op, an increment and a mux to select between the two next states.

Answer (score 0):

Design the state transitions for 6 and 7 as well (next state = anything but 6 or 7.  2 is OK.)  Otherwise a glitch may cause your counter to lock up in an undefined state.  Use the "else" case if your design environment allows it.